# How to make different logged in users in firebase go to different pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I have it working that when a user is logged in it goes to a TabsPage but if not logged in go to log in page. The problem is I have two users a customer and an event organiser. So I want to do something like if (user.useType === "customer") go to TabsPage and if (user.useType === "eventorganiser") then go EventTabsPage else if not a user go to LoginPage.

I am trying user firebase snapshot but not working at all as always returns true. Am I close? I have userType in database that is either userType: "customer" or userType: "eventorganiser"

```
import { Reference } from '@firebase/database-types';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html',
})
export class MyApp {
rootPage: any;
public  type : Reference
constructor(platform: Platform,
statusBar: StatusBar,
splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
this.type = firebase.database().ref("userProfile");
this.type.once("value")
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    this.type  = snapshot.val().userType
  });

const unsubscribe: Unsubscribe = firebase
  .auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user && this.type.toString() === "customer") {
      this.rootPage = 'TabsPage'
      unsubscribe();
    }
    else if (user && this.type.toString() === "eventorganiser") {
      this.rootPage = 'EventTabsPage';
      unsubscribe();
    }
    else {
      this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
      unsubscribe();
    }
  });
```

database is like below

```
  {
"userProfile" : {
"3RQOUe9cqcRX2IMy0S290S9trSM2" : {
  "birthDate" : "2018-02-20",
  "email" : "acs@acs.com",
  "firstName" : "asda",
  "lastName" : "dsad",
  "userType" : "customer"
},
  "CHtJTfDmCgfaMY91ve4oepvIkuc2" : {
  "birthDate" : "2018-02-20",
  "email" : "liam@liam.com",
  "firstName" : "lk",
  "lastName" : "",
  "userType" : "eventorganiser"
},
```

my working code for all users is below

```
   const unsubscribe: Unsubscribe = firebase
  .auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged(user  => {
    if (user) {
      this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
      unsubscribe();
    } else {
      this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
      unsubscribe();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that by the time your apps calls:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user && this.type.toString() === "customer") {
      this.rootPage = 'TabsPage'
      unsubscribe();
    }
```

The:

```
this.type = firebase.database().ref("userProfile");
this.type.once("value")
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    this.type  = snapshot.val().userType
  });
```

Is not ready, because it's an async call and it's not waiting for the value to return before calling your `onAuthStateChanged()` function.

Also, make sure please that's the correct reference, because /userType is a generic node.

Here's how I've done this in the past:

```
const unsubscribe: Unsubscribe = firebase
  .auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      firebase.database().ref("userProfile").once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val().userType === 'customer') {
          this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
        } else {
          this.rootPage = 'EventTabsPage'
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
      unsubscribe();
    }
  });
```

Following that flow, it first gets the user, then the user profile, and then checks the values.